# POSTed arrays keeping old values

Tags: php, html, post

Yesterday I noticed one of my websites is behaving in a very strange way: whenever I update a post from its admin area, some of its extra inputs keep the values they already have (all of them are multi-dimensional arrays). For example:

*HTML in the "edit post" page*

```
<input type="text" id="field_a0b" class="text" name="fields[a][0][b]" 
value="Current value" placeholder="">
```

If I edit that post manually (as an end user would), changing `Current value` to `New value`, then hit the *Update post* button, `$_POST['fields']['a'][0]['b']` will still contain `Current value` - not `New value` as I would expect.

This only happens with those input arrays. Also, if I change `name="fields[a][0][b]"` to something random, like `name="fields[a][0][bbbbbbbb]"` in the final HTML (with Chrome dev tools, for example), and repeat the process, then I get the value I entered in the input field!

I first thought the problem was the amount of input fields or the way those arrays are being nested, but I tried increasing `max_input_nesting_level` and `max_input_vars` (and even `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`) in my `php.ini` and I'm still getting the same results.

I've hacked the framework files to dump data from multiple places (even from the bootstrap step), still with no success.